# Calculating LRC in java

Tags: java

I want to calculate LRC for the following message:

```
T = 0101 0100
P = 0101 0000
1 = 0011 0001
2 = 0011 0010


Starting with 0x00 as the initial byte.

0 XOR ‘T’:         0000 0000
0101 0100
Result, LRC =    0101 0100


LRC XOR ‘P’:    0101 0100
                        0101 0000
Result, LRC =    0000 0100


LRC XOR ‘1’:    0000 0100
                        0011 0001
Result, LRC =    0011 0101


LRC XOR ‘2’:    0011 0101
                        0011 0010
Result, LRC =    0000 0111
```

The code i have tried so far is shown below:

```
public class TexttoBinary {

private static final int maxBytes = 1;

public static int convert(char number) {

   // BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.print("Type the number to parse: ");
    //int number = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
    int Bit;
    //char number = '1';
    //UInt8 i;
    String result = "";
    for (int i = maxBytes * 7; i >=0; i--) {
        Bit = 1 << i;
        if (number >= Bit) {
            result += 1;
            //System.out.println(result);
            number -= Bit;
        } else {
            result += 0;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(result);
   return Integer.parseInt(result);
}
public static void main(String args[]){
    String msg ="TP12";
    char[] toCharArray = msg.toCharArray();
    char lrc=0;
    for(int i=0;i<toCharArray.length;i++)
    lrc ^=convert(toCharArray[i]);
    System.out.println((byte)lrc);
}
```

}

The output i am getting is something different. What do i do now ?

Comment: What you do now is debug your code.

Comment: @dkamins: LRC is Longitudinal redundancy check

Comment: @ Oli Charlesworth: I am trying this for very long time :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you are talking about a longitudinal redundancy check; when in doubt, [check you algorithm against published examples](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longitudinal_redundancy_check).

[Here's one in Java](https://gist.github.com/953550), which seems quite different than yours.  Perhaps yours is some attempt to optimize the LRC using DeMorgan's theorm, but odds are good it picked up a mistake along the way.

Comment: but that doesn gives me 8 bit LRC. How do i get 8 bit LRC from tat ?

Comment: @Deepak, a byte is defined to be eight bits.  XOR operates bit wise, so XORing two bytes is exactly the same as looping through and XORing one byte at a time.

Comment: I figured it out !! That number 97 was in some other format. When i get 54 it is in ASCII format and when i convert it to character i get 7 and thats what i want. Is that right ?

Answer (score 0):

following code is working for me in java for validation of credit card magnetic strip read. [see it running online here.](https://ideone.com/CTzWxn)

```
String str = ";4564456445644564=1012101123456789?";
byte lrc = 0x00;
byte [] binaryValue = str.getBytes();

for(byte b : binaryValue) {

    lrc ^= b;
}

// lrc msut be between 48 to 95
lrc %= 48; 
lrc += 48;

System.out.println("LRC: " + (char) lrc);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String lrc2hex (String str) {
    byte[] bytes = str.getBytes ();
    int lrc = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length (); i++) {
        lrc ^= (bytes[i] & 0xFF);
    }
    return String.format ("%02X ", lrc);
}
...

String data = "0200|666|0|0" + "\u0003";       // Includes a non-visible character
System.out.println ("DATA: " + data);          // DATA: 0200|666|0|0
System.out.println ("LRC: " + lrc2hex (data)); // LRC: 4B
```

Run a demo: https://www.jdoodle.com/a/qWQ

More info: https://asecuritysite.com/calculators/lrc?a=0200|666|0|0%03

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me.

```
public static byte CalcLRC(byte[] bytes) {
    byte LRC = 0x00;
    for (byte aByte : bytes) {
        LRC = (byte) ((LRC + aByte) & 0xFF);
    }
    return (byte)(((LRC ^ 0xFF) + 1) & 0xFF);
}
```